# Image to Pixel values

Tags: python, image, numpy, compression, python-imaging-library

So I am working on image compression. I am trying to  first convert an input image into pixel values and save it into a file. But my output file is already larger (in size) than the original image. Is there away I can work around it, so my output file is less than or equal to the original image file before doing any compression?

Comment: does [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38198379/how-to-change-the-pixel-values-of-an-image) help?

Comment: You've uncompressed an image and are surprised it's bigger?